# Android - loopJ AsyncHttpClient return response onFinish or onSuccess

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, loopj, asynchttpclient

I am looking for a way to return the response I get in loopJ AsyncHttpClient onFinish or onSuccess or onFailure. As of now I have this piece of code:

```
**jsonParse.java file**
public class jsonParse {
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String jsonString = "";
    AsyncHttpClient client;

      public JSONObject getJSONObj() {
            RequestParams params;
            params = new RequestParams();
            params.add("username", "user");
            params.add("password", "password");
            client = new AsyncHttpClient();
            client.post("http://example.com", params, new TextHttpResponseHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int i, Header[] headers, String response) {
                    jsonString = response;
                    Log.d("onSuccess: ", jsonString);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String response, Throwable e) {
                    if (statusCode == 401) {
                        jsonString = response;
                        Log.d("onFailure: ", jsonString);
                    }
                }

            });
            try {
                jObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Exception", "JSONException " + e.toString());
            }
            return jObj;
        }
}
```

When I invoke the code:

```
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl();
```

I get the **JSONException** before onSuccess or onFailure method finishes the http post.

I have noticed that, on the first invoke: 
Log.e("Exception", "JSONException " + e.toString()); is getting logged and then Log.d("onSuccess: ", jsonString); logs the value as they are in the sync state.

On the second invoke:
 jObj = new JSONObject(jsonString); gets executed successfully and I get desired return value for the method, because by that time onSuccess method would have already assigned the value to the variable jsonString.

Now what I am exactly looking for is a way to prevent **premature** return of jObj from the method.

**Is there anyway to make the method, getJSONObj, wait for the completion of AsyncHttpClient task, assign the variable into jsonString, create the JSONObject and return it?**

Thanks in advance!
Cheers!

Comment: @mapo87 thanks for the early reply. I have a question about retrofit, does it support https post and persistent Cookie Store?

Comment: https: yes, cookies: you need to set this up, but yes

Comment: @mapo87 Thanks for the reply. I will see to it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an interface. This way you can create your own callback whose methods can be called from onSuccess or onFailure.

```
public interface OnJSONResponseCallback {
    public void onJSONResponse(boolean success, JSONObject response);
}

public JSONObject getJSONObj(OnJSONResponseCallback callback) {
    ...
   @Override
   public void onSuccess(int i, Header[] headers, String response) {
       try {
           jObj = new JSONObject(response);
           callback.onJSONResponse(true, jObj);
       } catch (JSONException e) {
           Log.e("Exception", "JSONException " + e.toString());
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String response, Throwable e) {
       try {
           jObj = new JSONObject(response);
           callback.onJSONResponse(false, jObj);
       } catch (JSONException e) {
           Log.e("Exception", "JSONException " + e.toString());
       }
   }
}
```

And to call it:

```
jsonParse.getJSONObj(new OnJSONResponseCallback(){
    @Override
    public void onJSONResponse(boolean success, JSONObject response){
       //do something with the JSON
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks! I am really a newbie to android and java development. Can I have a reference url to such an example? Cheers :)

Comment: @justine powell 
I followed your code and I got an exception. Would you please mind going through the exception? http://pastebin.com/gHwzdhxa


ps: I have declared the variable on the top:
**OnJSONResponseCallback callback**;

The line `callback.onJSONResponse(false, jObj);` is reason behind this exception. any ideas? :)

Comment: It means your callback is null here. You shouldn't define the callback here, you should define it from wherever you call getJSONObj (as I showed as an example in my answer).

Comment: man!! you are super awesome! exactly what I wanted! :) well i learned a thing or two today!

Good day, Sir!

Answer (score 1):

Use [retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit). It manages the http request very good and converts the json objects automatically to your Java objects. There is also a failure and success Callback. You can also decide whether the request is async or sync.